# Applicative instance for a tuple with monoid and function inside

Tags: scala, scalaz, applicative, monoids

I was trying to convert a haskell example, I came across earlier, to scalaz. The original example was this:

```
("Answer to the ", (*)) <*> ("Ultimate Question of ", 6) <*> ("Life, the Universe, and Everything", 7)
```

Which, as far as I am able to understand, uses [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Applicative.html#line-199) instance.

It does not get converted to scalaz literally:

```
scala> ("Answer to the ", ((_: Int) * (_: Int)) curried) |@| ("Ultimate Question of ", 6) |@| ("Life, the Universe, and Everything", 7) tupled
res37: (java.lang.String, (Int => (Int => Int), Int, Int)) = (Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything,(<function1>,6,7))
```

Although, I've looked for an instance, and it seems to [be there](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Applicative.scala#L39) (again, as far as I am able to understand).

So, the question is: why does not it work like this? Or what did I miss/did not get correctly?

Comment: This code does indeed dispatch to the applicative instance for tuples. Which in turn uses the monoid `mappend` for lists (concatentation). So it is function composition of the 2nd component of the tuple, with list concatentation of the first part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scalaz's equivalent of `Control.Applicative`'s `<*>` is also called `<*>`, although it confusingly takes its arguments in the opposite order. So the following works:

```
val times = ((_: Int) * (_: Int)) curried
val a = "Answer to the "
val b = "Ultimate Question of "
val c = "Life, the Universe, and Everything"

(c, 7) <*> ((b, 6) <*> (a, times))
```

Or, as I've noted in response to your comment, you could use the following if you want to stick with `|@|`:

```
(a -> times |@| b -> 6 |@| c -> 7)(_ apply _ apply _)
```

I personally prefer the `<*>` version, even if it feels backwards.

---

We can walk through what's going on in a little more detail. First of all, you don't need the full power of `Applicative` here—`Apply` will do. We can get the `Apply` instance for tuples using `implicitly`:

```
scala> val ai = implicitly[Apply[({type λ[α]=(String, α)})#λ]]
ai: scalaz.Apply[[α](java.lang.String, α)] = scalaz.Applys$$anon$2@3863f03a
```

Now we can apply our first tuple to the second:

```
scala> :t ai(a -> times, b -> 6)
(java.lang.String, Int => Int)
```

And the result to the third:

```
scala> :t ai(ai(a -> times, b -> 6), c -> 7)
(java.lang.String, Int)
```

Which is what we want:

```
scala> ai(ai(a -> times, b -> 6), c -> 7)._1
res0: java.lang.String = Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything

scala> ai(ai(a -> times, b -> 6), c -> 7)._2
res1: Int = 42
```

The `<*>` method on `MA` just wraps this up a little more nicely.

Comment: Thanks, works like it is supposed to. By the way, do you have any idea, how to do this with the ApplicativeBuilder and if it will look any better that way?

Comment: Sure, you could do something like `(a -> times |@| b -> 6 |@| c -> 7)(_ apply _ apply _)`, but I think the `<*>` version is nicer.

Comment: Yep, this works. I was mislead by the fact, that `tupled` glued up the monoid, so I thought, it would apply the function too.